# Looping through array of objects after button press

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to loop through array of objects to display them on a grid based off of input values for my library project. My code for loop is:

```js
const addBook = (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    let myLibrary = [];
    let bookInfo = {
      title: document.getElementById('title').value,
      author: document.getElementById('author').value,
      pages: document.getElementById('pages').value,
    }
    myLibrary.push(bookInfo)
    for (i = 0; i < myLibrary.length; i++) {
      console.log(myLibrary)
      var container = document.getElementById('book-shelf')
      var div = document.createElement('div')
      div.classList.add('cell')
      container.appendChild(div);
    }
    var submitBtn = document.querySelector('.submit-btn');
    submitBtn.addEventListener('click', addBook)
```

Each time I enter title,author, and pages value and click submit button, it goes through and gives me a cell. If try to add another book, it gives me 3 cells rather then 2. Doing another add gives me 6 instead of 3. How can I make it where I can add a book each time one by one rather then it adding multiple times?

Comment: I've added your code to a snippet and clicked the Tidy button to improve the indentation. As you can see, you're missing an ending curly bracket `}` for the `addBook` function. So it is adding the event listener to the submit button every time you click it.

Comment: Also `document.getElementById('book-shelf').innerHTML = myLibrary.map(book => \`<div class="cell"><h3>${book.title}</h3><p>Author: ${book.author}<br/>Pages: ${book.pages}/p></div>\`).join("")`

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys! I'm still learning javascript you guys have been really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

There are three main issues.

1. A missing curly brace after the function and before the button listener.
2. `myLibrary` is being redefined each time the function is called which is one of the reasons you're having to look over the data each time. You want to define it outside the function so you can add one book at a time to it when `addBook` is called.
3. With `myLibrary` no longer being redefined each time there's no need for the loop. We can just add the HTML for the book to the book shelf `onSubmit`.

(Note: In this working example (I've added some HTML for a table, and the inputs and buttons, and created some code to add the new book to the shelf), I've renamed the `myLibrary` variable to `bookShelf` to keep things consistent with the HTML naming.)

```js
// Cache all the elements up front
const titleEl = document.getElementById('title');
const authorEl = document.getElementById('author');
const pagesEl = document.getElementById('pages');
const bookshelfEl = document.getElementById('bookshelf');
const submitBtn = document.querySelector('.submit-btn');

// Add the listener
submitBtn.addEventListener('click', addBook, false);

titleEl.focus();

// Our bookShelf variable is now
// outside the function
const bookShelf = [];

function addBook() {

  // Because we've cached the elements
  // we can now just grab the values from each
  const bookInfo = {
    title: titleEl.value,
    author: authorEl.value,
    pages: pagesEl.value,
  }

  bookShelf.push(bookInfo);

  // Once we've added our book we can grab the
  // title, author, and pages variables from it
  const { title, author, pages } = bookInfo;

  // Create a row for the table
  const row = document.createElement('tr')

  // Create some HTML and add it to the div
  row.innerHTML = `
     <td>${title}</td>
     <td>${author}</td>
     <td>${pages}</td>
  `;

  bookshelfEl.appendChild(row);

}
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; border: 2px solid #565656; width: 100%; }
td { text-align: center; }
.heading { background-color: #efefef; border-top: solid thin #565656; }
tr { border: solid thin #ababab; }
```

```html
<input placeholder="Title" id="title" />
<input placeholder="Author" id="author" />
<input placeholder="Pages" id="pages" />
<button type="button" class="submit-btn">Submit</button>
<H3>Book shelf</H3>
<table>
  <tbody id="bookshelf">
    <tr class="heading">
      <td>Title</td>
      <td>Author</td>
      <td>Pages</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Additional documentation

- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [Template/string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with the loop. Each time you click the submit button, you add a cell for each item in `myLibrary` in this block:

```
for (i = 0; i < myLibrary.length; i++) {
      console.log(myLibrary)
      var container = document.getElementById('book-shelf')
      var div = document.createElement('div')
      div.classList.add('cell')
      container.appendChild(div);
    }
```

I don't think you need to loop through the array each time. Just add the cell directly whenever you are adding bookInfo data to `myLibrary`, without using `for` loop e.g

```
const addBook = (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    let myLibrary = [];
    let bookInfo = {
      title: document.getElementById('title').value,
      author: document.getElementById('author').value,
      pages: document.getElementById('pages').value,
    }
    myLibrary.push(bookInfo)
    var container = document.getElementById('book-shelf')
    var div = document.createElement('div')
    div.classList.add('cell')
    container.appendChild(div);
}
var submitBtn = document.querySelector('.submit-btn');
submitBtn.addEventListener('click', addBook)
```

Comment: For your second example to work `myLibrary` would have to be defined outside of the function otherwise there will always be only one book displayed.

Comment: @Andy that's true however the data from `myLibrary` isn't used anywhere in my version of code and is left as is for whatever other purpose op may need it. I don't see how you derived the conclusion that it will have effect on the display of the book's data?